# Why does following call to a label exit the script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have created a label `:checkNetworkDrive` to test a condition:

```
:checkNetworkDrive  
setlocal

if not exist %drive%\ (
    echo The specified drive does not exist
    exit /b 1
)
exit /b 0
```

Now the call to this label from 2 calls work differently. Call to **label1** works correctly i.e. exists/not exists is printed, while call from **label 2** exits the entire script. Is it due to presence of `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` in label 2?

### label1:

```
set drive=...
call :checkNetworkDrive 
if %errorlevel% == 1 (
    echo "exists"
) else ( 
    echo "not exist"
)
```

### label2:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set drive=...
call :checkNetworkDrive 
if %errorlevel% == 1 (
    echo "exists"
) else ( 
    echo "not exist"
)
```

Comment: The code you showed, isn't the cause for the problem. Perhaps you have a second label `:checkNetworkDrive`. Did you try if the `:checkNetworkDrive` will be executed from label2 before exiting? Add an `echo CHECKDRIVE "%drive%"` at the beginning of the function, probably the content of `drive` is evil.

Comment: I would suggest you first of all take a step back from the script and decide whether you're checking for the existence of a drive, the availability of one, or whether the specific user has permissable access to it. It may turn out that `If Exist` is not really what you want.